# How to use - with Slicing in Python?

Tags: python

```
animals = ["dog","cat","lion","elephant"]

animals[-1:-3]
```

What is wrong with this?

Gives me blank result

Comment: You can't slice from right to left with a positive step (it defaults to `1`), did you want `[-3:-1]` (which would be `['cat', 'lion']`)?

Comment: syntax is `[start:stop]` under no circumstance start can be greater than stop. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Comment: Thank You @venky__
animals[-3:-1] - This would have been my required syntax for the result. Cheers!

Comment: @venky__ the syntax is `[start:stop:step]`, so `start` can be greater than `stop` if `step < 0`